# Back and Forward buttons

Tags: java, gwt

Back and Forward buttons are disabled in Chrome in my GWT project, i consider it as a weird behavior. From the browser point of view, i m not talking about gwt History.
Just when i run my gwt project then back and forward buttons are disabled, any ideas ?
If i first implement gwt History, then should they work for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back and forward buttons are disabled when there is no history. When you open a GWT app in a new tab/window it will have no history so back and forward buttons will be disabled.

Since GWT is pure JS and it does not reload the page (i.e. it runs within one page), history will not be changed even if you navigate UI in your GWT app.

To have history support in GWT you need to explicitly enable it: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html

Comment: Thanks Peter!You are right, after i implement History it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that the HTML(/XML/XHTML/whatever..) pumped out by GWT is valid according to the spec.  If not, it is pretty much guess-work as to how an UA (browser) will parse it.